# How to Make Radio Button Show/Hide Input Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a site and I would like to know how to make my radio buttons show / hide input fields.

The site im using only allows me to edit the css and javascript only so I can't change the html but there are IDs on the radio buttons and input fields.

Essentially I am working on a product page and want to only show one dropdown when someone only chooses to buy one product with the others hidden. Then have the second show up if they select the buy two radio button...etc

[https://codepen.io/adrian-england/pen/bmKPxO][1]

HTML

```
Buy One <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="one">

Buy Two <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="two">

Buy Three <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="three">

Buy Four <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="three">

  <br>
<select id="first">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
   <br>
<select id="second">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
   <br>
<select id="third">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
  <br>
<select id="fourth">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.visible { display: block; }
.hidden { display: none;}
```

JS

```
function hideSelector (){
    var seltwo = document.getElementById("second");

    seltwo.addClass("hidden");
};

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", hideSelector);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using purely JavaScript and not jQuery you want to add to the classList:

```
function hideSelector (){
    var seltwo = document.getElementById("second");
    seltwo.classList.add("hidden");
};

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", hideSelector);
```

If you want to use jQuery then you can use it to select the element as so:

```
function hideSelector (){
    var seltwo = $("#second");
    seltwo.addClass("hidden");

    // Additionally you could one line this $('#second').addClass('hidden');
};

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", hideSelector);
```